# Pattern Matching a List[_] in Scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-erasure

I have the Following Code

```
def function1(obj:Any)={

obj match {


        case l:List[Map[String,Any]]=> {
          println("ListMap" + l.toString())
        }
        case l:List[String]=> {
          println ("list String" + l)
        }
        case None =>
      }
}
```

When I pass a List Of Maps and String to this function, it keeps printing only the first case statement, it doesn't go the second one. Is there anything I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Why would it go to the second one? That's horrible code using `Any` btw, there's little point in using a type system like that. The whole point of case statements is to eval once per case, to match a given condition.

Comment: You should get a Warning about type erasure in there - the second case will never match. In general you can not rely on type checking via ```x : A[Type]``` of generic code in a pattern, only on real type matchers (i.e. objects which have an unapply method).

Comment: I have to use Any because my data is that way.... I have no choice

Comment: You can make the function generic too: ```def f[T](obj : T) = obj match { case Nil => ... ; case x::xs => ...```. If you need to process obj, you can pass an additional argument of type ```T => ResultType```.

Comment: It is not possible because of type erasure (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). It is not possible at runtime to detect type parameter of the generic type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that both of them are `List` (the function is just checking the `outer` `dataType` and ignoring the `inner dataType`.
You can use the following solution for your case and modify as you need.

```
 def function(obj: Any) : Unit = {
   Try {
     obj.asInstanceOf[List[Map[String, Any]]].map(function2(_))
     println("ListMap")
   }getOrElse (
     Try{
        obj.asInstanceOf[List[String]].map(function2(_))
        println("List of String")
     }getOrElse
       println("do nothing")
     )
 }
```

The reason for the necessary of `function2` is that without `transformation` the `casted datatype` is not recognised. You need some `transformation` in the data you pass to the `function` anyway

```
 def function2(obj: Any) = obj match {
   case _ : Map[String, Any] => //do what you want with your map
   case _ : String => //do what you want with your string list
   case _  => // this is not done for now
 }
```

I hope this is exactly what you are looking for

Comment: This makes sense but shouldn't we be checking for a Failure because you have it wrapped in a Try {}

Comment: Failures are catched by `gerOrElse` so we don't need to explicitly check for `Failure`

Answer (score 2):

What about the following sketch (types depend on your usage):

```
def f[T](obj : List[T], trans : T => String) = obj.map(trans).mkString
```

Then you call `f` as follows:

```
scala> f[Map[Int,Int]](List(Map(1->2, 3->4), Map(0->0)), _.toList.map( x => (x._1 - x._2).toString).mkString(","))
res5: String = -1,-10

scala> f[String](List("abc","def","ghi"), x => x.reverse)
res6: String = cbafedihg
```